# poll the status of CTS line in windows

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

Hi stackoverflow users!

I need to poll the CTS line of my serial port in Windows environment, 
I have opened successfully the COM port,

```
HANDLE hSerialIn;
const char* pcCommPort = TEXT("COM3");
hSerialIn = CreateFile(pcCommPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, \
                       0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

Then I want to have something like this

```
DCB dcb = { 0 };

while (GetCommState(hSerialIn, &dcb)) {
    if (dcb.fOutxCtsFlow)
        ;
    else
        ;
}
```

The background of my interest in COM port is that there, I have a USB->UART convertor which in connected to the trigger output of the measuring device, this device triggers the output each second, and I want to have it in my program. When I connect to the COM port via Hercules(Terminal app) it works, I see that my CTS line is changing each second. So how to check the state of the CTS line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be picky, you want to toggle RTS (request to send), which is an output, that should be connected to CTS (clear to send), which is an input. These signals are only present in RS-232, not in USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DWORD dwModemStatus; 
BOOL fCTS = 0; 

if (!SetCommMask(hSerialIn, EV_CTS)) 
{ 
    DWORD err = GetLastError(); 
    printf("\nHandle creation error code: %x\n", err); 
} 

DWORD dwCommEvent; 

while(1) 
{ 
    if (!WaitCommEvent(hSerialIn, &dwCommEvent, NULL)) // An error occurred waiting for the event. 
        printf(""); 
    else 
    { 
        if (!GetCommModemStatus(hSerialIn, &dwModemStatus)) // Error in GetCommModemStatus; 
            return; 
        fCTS = MS_CTS_ON & dwModemStatus; 

        if(fCTS) 
            printf("%x ", fCTS); 
    }  
}
```